# how to bind dictionary to datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, datagrid

i am trying to bind a dictionary to datagrid , for now couldn't found a clear way of doing if.
the dictionary key should be the grid header and its values should be the column data.
for example 
C# Code:

```
var dictionary  = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dictionary.Add("First Name","Name");
dictionary.Add("Last Name","Last Name");  
dictionary.Add("Phone","+123-123-123");
```

meaning i would like my datagrid to have 3 colunms:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Phone

is there a way of bind a dictionary with unknown number of Keys , to datagrid ?
for now i'm using Datatable instead
thanks

Comment: in the way you define it this datagrid will always have only 1 row which doesnt make much sense

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want would be as follows:

In the `CodeBehind`, you can create an list of `Anonymus` objects, if you no have an model, and int the constructor populate the list and add to `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid`:

```
List<Object> mylist = new List<Object>(){
new {FirstName="myfirstName1", LastName="mylastName1", Phone="+123-123-123"},
new {FirstName="myfirstName2", LastName="mylastName2", Phone="+124-124-124"},
new {FirstName="myfirstName3", LastName="mylastName3", Phone="+125-125-125"}
}

this.myDataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;
```

In the `XAML` you place the following code, as statement of `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirsName}" Header="First name"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last name"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Phone"  />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear on the first time , the number of fields (keys) is unknown.

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear on the first time , the number of fields (keys) is unknown nor there names. If ill work with anonymous objects ill still have to create an object with a defined properties.

Comment: what you are tried to do? You could tell me what is your intention with this solution?

Comment: Do not you think it would be better to show the properties vertically, rather than horizontally in the form of columns?

If you do this vertically their solution with Dictionary was surely the best.

Answer (score 0):

i'll try to be more specific.
let say i'm getting a list of objects for example table .
each table can have a different data structure and also different number of rows.
so i cannot be bound to any data structure.
for now the best solution i found is to bound by grid to DataTable

```
var selectedTable = new DataTable();
        if (tableEntities.Any())
        {
            var colunms = table.Properties;
            foreach (var colunm in colunms)
            {
                selectedTable.Columns.Add(colunm.Key);
            }

            foreach (var entity in tableEntities)
            {
                var row = selectedTable.NewRow();
                foreach (var property in entity.Properties)
                {
                    row[property.Key] = property.Value.GetStringValue();
                }
                selectedTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

but i don't like this solution